# How to make particular common array value to single array and other value to come under it

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've an array like below it as a common name but different surname. I want put all this name in to one array and the surname array inside the single array. Like the below one.

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Rahul
                [surname] => M
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Rahul
                [surname] => D
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Rahul
                [surname] => F
            )
)
```

I want the above to be like below

```
 Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [Name] => Rahul
        [surname] => Array(
            [0] => M
            [1] => D
            [2] => F
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: *"I want"* isn't a welcome way to ask a *question* there. Rather show us your attempts and what causes you issues instead of waiting for us to code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over main array and append it like:

```
<?
$names = [];
$names[0]['Name'] = 'Rahul';
$names[1]['Name'] = 'Rahul';
$names[2]['Name'] = 'Rahul';
$names[0]['surname'] = 'M';
$names[1]['surname'] = 'D';
$names[2]['surname'] = 'F';
$commonNames = [];
if (! empty($names)) {
 foreach($names as $name) {
  $commonNames[0][$name['Name']][] = $name['surname'];
 }
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($commonNames);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
 (
 [Rahul] => Array
  (
   [0] => M
   [1] => D
   [2] => F
   )
 )
)
```

[Working Code:](https://3v4l.org/ukbeu)

Comment: This 1 itried. Thank you. There is any particular function to achieve it,.. May be using array_map

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
$temp = [];
array_walk($arr, function($item,$key) use(&$temp){
    $temp[$item['Name']]['Name'] = $item['Name'];
    $temp[$item['Name']]["surname"][] = $item['surname'];
});
$temp = array_values($temp);
print_r($temp);
```

[array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) — Return all the values of an array
[array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) — Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a1016bc89bc16790d2bf2f8c1484990af76ec16b).